# Reordering Reports in Jasper Reports/iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'd like to rearrange the order that my reports appear in Jaspersoft.  I've tried just dragging the highlighted report up the list in both iReport and in Jaspersoft itself, but neither option worked for me.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It looks like the only way to modify the order is with the SORT BY option in Jasper - those options are by Name or by Modified Date.  Anybody know of any other option?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  You could use folders to organize your reports differently, or prefix your report names.